# Emacs 24 Cedet Semantic autocomplete menu

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, cedet

Emacs 24 doesn't support semantic-ia-complete-symbol-menu, meaning that I have to use semantic-ia-complete-symbol which shows the suggestions in a new buffer. I have read that there is a way to get auto-complete to use the semantic suggestions, but can't figure out how.

Is there a way to show the suggestions from semantic in some other form than a new buffer, e.g. as a menu, inline, etc?

Comment: BTW, in Emacs's trunk, `semantic-ia-complete-symbol-menu` now works as well (tho only when the completion info is precise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about auto-complete, but `company-mode` (which is in GNU ELPA, hence can be installed directly via `M-x package-install`) provides this out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ac-complete-semantic instead.